# retrieve text value from text object

Tags: text, fabricjs

I would like to know how to retrieve text (IText / Text) value from text object?

```
var textObj = new fabric.IText('hello friends', { left: 100, top: 100 });
canvas.add(textObj);
```

So how I can retrieve the text value of 'textObj'?

Comment: Have you tried `getText` http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.IText.html#getText ?

Comment: so its retrieve using textObj.getText(), right? I tried but not getting the value.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have to use var text = canvas.getActiveObject() & then should text.getText()

Comment: Yes. Make sure `canvas.getActiveObject()` actually returns an `IText` instance by using `.get('type')` on it.

Comment: For anyone else who ends up here: it seems that `.getText()` is gone in Fabric 2.x, instead you can use `.get('text')`

Answer (score 4):

`textObj.text` or `textObj.get('text')` works on Fabricjs `2.x`

To get the text from the selected object

```
const obj = canvas.getActiveObject()

if (obj && obj.isType('textbox')) {
  const { text } = obj
  // ...
}
```